# Trying to make a code only bundle in Shopify Dawn theme

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I'm trying to make a bundle in shopify using only liquid code. Like if I have a bag and it's added to cart, a jacket is added with it automatically. I'm a rookie in Shopify so if someone could give me some leads as in where should I start.

I tried adding an event listener for clicking on the ATC button but I can't extract the product id on the product page. I'm desperate for some leads on this Thank you!
And how can I check that what's happening once the Add to cart button is clicked?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, when the customer clicks the ATC button on a product, you want to add an extra product to the cart besides the one the customer is actually adding.

Usually I prefer the [AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart) for this approach. Take a look at this code:

```html
<script>
const addToCartBtn = document.querySelector("#addToCart")

addToCartBtn.addEventListener('click', async function() {
  const extraItem = {
    items: [
      {
        id: 44714049634597, // ID of the variant you want to add to the cart
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const response = await fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(extraItem),
  });

  if (!response.ok) console.log('Upss something went wrong');

  console.log(await respons.json());
});
</script>
```

Basically what this code does is that when the user clicks the ATC button, we send a request to the cart/add API with the extra Item as the body of the request. Learn how to get the variant ID [here.](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/variants/find-variant-id)

If you want to make this function more dynamic and reusable, try using metafields. Go to the admin dashboard and [create a product metafield](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/custom-data/metafields/using-metafields#what-you-39-ll-learn) to help you reference the desired product. So now the request body should look like this:

```js
  const extraItem = {
    items: [
      {
        id: {{ product.metafields.custom.bundle_product.id }}
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Since we are using liquid now, make sure to place this code inside a script tag in the main-product.liquid file (also named product.liquid in some themes).

Hope this helps!